# PHP Artisan doesn't work properly, when typing php artisan in command line

Tags: php, lumen

I get such an error while typing php artisan in command line:

> Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Support\Env' not found in /Users/rashadnagiev/Desktop/paylink/api/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Bootstrap/LoadEnvironmentVariables 2.php:68

Comment: Check if you have .env file in preoject.

Comment: Try composer update --no-scripts and composer install in project directory

Comment: try composer dump-autoload